# cmake, can I make executable binary with shared library(include static library)?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have:

- executable binary: `sampleApp`
- shared library: `libsample.so`
- static library: `libsamplecore.a`

When I check samplApp like below

```
objdump -x sampleApp | grep "samplecoreAPI"
```

I can not find the symbol of `libsamplecore.a`.
(But I can find the symbol of `libsamplecore.a` in `libsample.so`.)

I just added below in `CMakeLists.txt` of `sampleApp`:

```
target_link_libraries($(PROJECT) PRIVATE ${SAMPLE_LIBRARY} ... )
```

What should I do more?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what is going on without seeing a more complete version of your CMake code. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this issue.

Comment: Perhaps this is normal operation. So I just want to know the relationship between binary,shared lib,static lib in theory.

Comment: "So I just want to know the relationship between binary,shared lib,static lib in theory".
There is no answer to that. The relationship depends entirely on your linkage,
which we do not know without the relevant `CMake` code.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was not enough. Anyway I concluded that is normal. Thanks.